# Retrieving a particular value from a key

Tags: c#

I have stored multiple key values as below in a static function.

```
 public static class ElementID
    {
        static Dictionary<String, String> store = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public static void keyvalue()
        {      
           //Login
            store.Add("Name","USERNAME");
            store.Add("Password", "PASSWORD");
            store.Add("Login", "Login");     
      }
```

}

Now i want to use the first value "USERNAME" in the below driver command

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("")).Click();
```

Can anyone tell how is it possible to Use the value "USERNAME" of the key "Name" inside the `"By.Name("")".`

Like in Java we store the key value pair in a property file and retrieve the value from the same as below.

```
driver.findElement(By.name(property.getProperty("Name"))).click();
```

How can that be done in C# ?

Comment: This question is not about Appium or Selenium. This is actually about C# only.

Comment: Well , i am relating this concept of c# with the selenium web-driver commands , please look at the below answers clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking how you can access the value of a dictionary, the answer is: `store["Name"]`.
So the full line would be

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name(store["Name"])).Click();
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, I didnt declare with the "public" keyword hence i wasnt able to use the variable "Store" in another class. Thanks Thomas :)